# set-default-source doesn't work, set-default-sink does 20.04

Tags: soundcard, default

I want to set default audio devices for my Ubuntu 20.04.

First, why in the world would Sound not allow setting default devices?

So I tried manually.  Term window.
pactl list short sinks   %% gives me a list of devices, so I use

pactl set-default-sink 'alsa_output.usb-.......alsa-card.c'  %% no errors

The output device changes in the Sound app.

But if I do

pactl list short sources  %% which lists sources, and I select and use one:

pactl set-default-sourc 'alsa_output.usb-0b0e_Jabra_Link_370_.....stereo.monitor'

Also no errors but the input device doesn't change in the Sound app - I have to manually change it.

Any ideas what gives?
Thanks!

Comment: Gee, the support for Ubuntu is overwhelming.  This would seem to be a common problem.  Solutions on the web are not working.  And also, every solution posted seems to go like this: "Add packages xdadfef, flurbl, whatnow, and fooboo." (not saying why), and then "change the following seven scripts" (not saying what the changes do), with random gui commands, each with complex sets of arguments.  There appears to be no easy way for a normal user to do anything.

Comment: My brother sells software to mid-tier companies, and he tells me Windows 10 crushes Ubuntu in terms of ease of use.  A high cost (in user time) for system settings and maintenance would seem to doom Ubuntu.  I see that Munich, after adopting Ubuntu for their city government, is switching to Win 10.  Does no one in the Ubuntu community care that the lack of a simple, reliable, and effective system setting interface is sinking Ubuntu?

Comment: I agree that it's a stupid oversight by Ubuntu in an area of user experience that makes such a difference to user satisfaction. I've tried a global config but that seems to be overridden by local configs or something else.

Comment: Wizard, I got it going by the procedure here https://askubuntu.com/questions/1317884/how-to-configure-the-default-sound-output-device/1317906#1317906