# How To Configure The Default Sound Output Device

Tags: sound, default, output

We all know that the output device for sound can be configured manually from

```
Settings > Sound > Output Device > <Dropdown List>
```

But it's very tiresome to see the device selected changed each time we restart the PC.
For some strange reason my PC has defaulted to my mobile phone lately !

*[I'd like to present a screenshot of this new addition to my sound output device list. But my screenshot generator (basically, press the Print Screen button on the keyboard) just does not function when a dropdown menu is shown ... Thanks, Ubuntu. ]*

With all other configurations the selected options are stored and applied on reboot - but not with the sound output device.

So is there a .conf file somewhere into which I can inscribe a favored output device ?

Answer (score 4):

After looking at [this post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1038490/how-do-you-set-a-default-audio-output-device-in-ubuntu-18-04), I got it going finally via:

```
pactl list short sinks
```

This provides a list of sound output devices. Find the one pertaining to your desired output device and copy its string name, e.g. 'alsa_output.pci-0000_00_1f.3.analog-stereo' for my laptop's built-in speakers.

Then use the command:

```
pactl set-default-sink 'alsa_output.pci-0000_00_1f.3.analog-stereo'
```

Reboot and check default device on Settings.
Now verify by going on YouTube and click on some video. It should play out of the desired speakers.

If you have more than one account (e.g. if you have an admin as well as an ordinary standard user account) then do the above procedure within each account.