# Default sound input device gets reset at every restart

Tags: sound, 22.04, default

Using 22.04 and my default input device gets reset at every reboot.
Looks like the settings from 'Sound' menu are not being saved - this is from a 'fresh' Ubuntu 22.04.1 install.

Is [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1317884/how-to-configure-the-default-sound-output-device) the only way to sort it out?
If yes - why is the UI non-functional?

Thanks?

---

I executed:

`pactl list short sources`

and then

`pactl set-default-source alsa_input.pci-0000_10_00.4.analog-stereo`

hopefully this should work but basic expectation is for the UI to be fully functional...

---

This solution doesn't even work. Disappointing.

Answer (score 0):

The command you listed worked for me. Here's what I input / output:

```
pactl list short sources
2   alsa_output.usb-Blue_Microphones_Yeti_Stereo_Microphone_REV8-00.analog-stereo.monitor   module-alsa-card.c  s16le 2ch 44100Hz   SUSPENDED
3   alsa_input.usb-Blue_Microphones_Yeti_Stereo_Microphone_REV8-00.analog-stereo    module-alsa-card.c  s16le 2ch 44100Hz   SUSPENDED
5   alsa_input.usb-046d_HD_Pro_Webcam_C920_E829CA2F-02.analog-stereo    module-alsa-card.c  s16le 2ch 32000Hz   SUSPENDED
6   alsa_output.usb-Logitech_PRO_X_Wireless_Gaming_Headset-00.analog-stereo.monitor module-alsa-card.c  s16le 2ch 48000Hz   IDLE
7   alsa_input.usb-Logitech_PRO_X_Wireless_Gaming_Headset-00.mono-fallback  module-alsa-card.c  s16le 1ch 44100Hz   IDLE
8   alsa_output.pci-0000_01_00.1.hdmi-stereo-extra1.monitor module-alsa-card.c  s16le 2ch 44100Hz   SUSPENDED
```

And I ran:

`pactl set-default-source alsa_output.usb-Logitech_PRO_X_Wireless_Gaming_Headset-00.analog-stereo.monitor` and it worked

Comment: The challenge I have is that when I plug in a USB or bluetooth device it messes the priority up, by giving the _dynamic_ device higher priority on what I had set before.